# Using Counting in a Sharepoint List using SP Online 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

How would I create a column that would count any results after I filtered a list?

So far I have tried =COUNT() but it did not work. I use a column name CostCenter

Comment: Do you need a count of the number of rows returned or the count of the contents of one column (number format)?

Comment: I need the Rows Returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the ribbon **List** --> **Modify view**. Scroll down to the **Totals** section and choose **count** for the column CostCenter.

Comment: Is there a way to have a a running column 1,2,3,4,5 or is the Count= X the only option?

Comment: Not sure, what you mean by a running column but the count=X is an inbuilt feature of the list view, if you need to modify it, it will be easier to go for other options involving some javascript.

Comment: Oh creating a new column which would count any visible rows

Comment: I don't think a column will help you to count visible rows on a list view in realtime. Column value will not update when you change filters on the view unless you have some event recievers firing to update the value. What i suggested using javascript, was maybe a way to count the <tr> for each row displayed (after applying filter) using js and display the result inline wherever you want.

Comment: Is there a way to display Count= X at the bottom of the list instead of the top of the list?

Comment: I haven't explored it but there could be, it is essentially a xslt listview webpart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21514/discussion-between-ransher-singh-and-michael-downey).